# CSS3 Button properties are showing different in iPad

Tags: ipad, button, css

I am using css3 for "button", It is running well on every browser but it's showing different in iPad. I think it takes the default properties of iPad so I apply 
**"-webkit-appearance:none;"** but it is not working.

My CSS Properties are -  **background:#1356b4; border:solid 1px #0e4189; border-radius:5px; transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out; -webkit-appearance:none;**.

And html code is simple span class button and input.

Please help me if someone having any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` we are telling mobile Safari that we explicitly don’t want our button to be styled like a native Apple UI control.